# Why does only Mono show up as scripting backend for PC, Mac & Standalone platform in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a project for which my build platform is PC, Mac & Standalone.  The only option for scripting backend is Mono.  I am expecting to see .NET and IL2CPP in the dropdown as I installed them when installing Unity 2017.3  If I switch the platform to UWP then I see .NET and IL2CPP in the scripting backend dropdown. I uninstalled and reinstalled Unity to see if this would clear it up and even went as far as unchecking Mono when reinstalling but still only Mono shows up for scripting backend for the  PC, Mac & Standalone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are scripting restrictions Unity 2017.3 and Mono is the only option for the Standalone platform:

https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/Manual/ScriptingRestrictions.html

Answer (score 1):

The IL2CPP scripting backend is available for standalone player builds in Unity 2018.1 and later. Prior to that version, only the Mono scripting backend was available.